# Join pandas Dataframe with Index of different length and keep all

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following:

```
i = pd.Index([1,2,3,4])
df = pd.DataFrame([11,22,44],index=[1,2,4])
```

I would like to do someting like:

```
df.merge(i, how='left')
```

To get:

```
1 11
2 22
3 Nan
4 44
```

However I can not merge a DataFrame with an Index, what is the idiomatic way of doing this in Pandas?

Update:
Given the following:

```
i = pd.Index([1,2,3,4])
df = pd.DataFrame([11,22,44,55],index=[1,2,4,5])
```

I would like to do someting like:

```
df.merge(i, how='left')
```

To get:

```
1 11
2 22
3 Nan
4 44
5 55
```

Comment: there is no `3`, it is typo?

Comment: no there is no 3 in the df, the index is not continuous there

Comment: But why in second df in output is index with 3 ?

Comment: @jezrael by "second output" you mean what is below the first "To get:"? That's the output he/she wants. It's an example to illustrate the expected outcome.

Comment: @kev - I think for second output `update` part of question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
print (df.reindex(i))
      0
1  11.0
2  22.0
3   NaN
4  44.0
```

EDIT:

If need reindex by `union`s of indices:

```
i = pd.Index([1,2,3])
df = pd.DataFrame([11,22,44,55],index=[1,2,4,5])
print (df)
    0
1  11
2  22
4  44
5  55

print (df.reindex(i.union(df.index)))
      0
1  11.0
2  22.0
3   NaN
4  44.0
5  55.0

print (df.reindex(i | df.index))
      0
1  11.0
2  22.0
3   NaN
4  44.0
5  55.0
```

Comment: My small example was wrong plz check my updated question

Comment: Not sure if understand, do you need `print (df.reindex(i.union(df.index)))` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([11,22,44,55], index=[1,2,4,5])

# guarantee dataframe index is sorted
df = df.sort_index()

idx = pd.DataFrame(index=range(df.index[0], df.index[-1]+1))
df = df.join(idx, how='outer')

#       0
# 1  11.0
# 2  22.0
# 3   NaN
# 4  44.0
# 5  55.0
```